# Translate MSSQL query to MySQL 5.7.23

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-5.7

I have a complicated SQL query running on a MSSQL server. I need to change it to make it work also on a MySQL database, however I do not know how to do this. The query is the following and is used to build a complicated Sankey graph in a BI tool

```
    SELECT Id, Delivery_Date, Queue, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7, 
CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,16),RAND((CHECKSUM(NEWID())))*(1 - 0.999999999)+0.999999999) as Counter
FROM
(SELECT t.ID as Id, t.DELIVERY_DATE as Delivery_Date, t.QUEUE as Queue, CONCAT(t.EVENT_NAME,' ', t.EVENT_STATUS, ' ',t .ENDING) as edsda,
'Step' + cast(row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID)
as varchar(10)) ColumnSeq

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT e.[ID] AS ID,
  e.[DIALOG_DELIVERY_DATE] AS DELIVERY_DATE,
  e.[QUEUE_ID] as QUEUE,
  s2.[STEP_NUMBER] AS STEP_NUMBER,
  s2.[CURRENT_EVENT] AS EVENT_NAME,
  s2.[EVENT_STATUS] as EVENT_STATUS,
  e.[DELIVERY_END] AS DELIVERY_END,
  CASE WHEN s2.[STEP_NUMBER] = max(s2.[STEP_NUMBER]) over (partition by s2.[ID]) 
and s2.[EVENT_NUMBER] = min(s2.[EVENT_NUMBER]) over (partition by s2.[ID], s2.[STEP_NUMBER]) THEN e.[DELIVERY_END] ELSE NULL END as ENDING
FROM [dbo].[DELIVERY_STEP_EVENTS] s1,
[dbo].[DELIVERY_STEP_EVENTS] s2,
[dbo].[DELIVERY_EVENTS] e
WHERE  s1.[ID] =  s2.[ID]
 AND e.[ID] = s2.[ID]
 AND s1.[EVENT_NAME] = s2.[EVENT_NAME]
 AND s1.[STEP_NUMBER] <= s2.[STEP_NUMBER] AS t) AS temp
pivot
(max(edsda)
for ColumnSeq in (Step1,Step2,Step3,Step4, Step5, Step6, Step7)
)
AS Piv
```

My biggest issue so far has been the RAND((CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) which I do not know how to change to MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For which MySQL version? `SELECT VERSION();`  Also which SQl Server version are you using?

Comment: If it is only the `RAND(checksum(newid))` part then just use `RAND()`. The behavior of MySQL rand is different from MS SQL, it is evaluated per row which is exactly what `RAND(checksum(newid))` trick is being used for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, sorry.  This question would have been better phrased had you just shown a couple of places where you couldn't figure out how to map the query.

Comment: Your biggest problem is the `OVER ()` clause, not `RAND` et al. That's just an attempt to create a different random number for each row. `OVER ()` is a problem because it was introduced in MySQL 8.0 and *can't* be emulated without complicated and slow subqueries

Comment: MSSQL `NEWID()` -> MySQL `UUID()`  MSSQL `CHECKSUM()` -> MySQL `CRC32()` (most likely)

Comment: "is a problem because it was introduced in MySQL 8.0 and can't be emulated without complicated and slow subqueries " Yes it can @PanagiotisKanavos there are two methodes 1) with a subquery  and MySQL user variable(s) which is fast and 2) the co-related subquery with `count(*)` is indeed slow..

Comment: @RaymondNijland what you call fast is actually very slow (it's a *cursor*) and *depends* on lack of parallel execution and generally undocumented behaviour that *did* change from version to version. So did performance. That's why adding those functions to MySQL 8 was a *big* deal

Comment: @RaymondNijland the quirky variable trick can't emulate the `PARTITION BY` or `ORDER BY` clauses either. It can only work on the entire result set using the result set's order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos performance is relative, for MySQL 8.0 version the MySQL user variables is the fastest method out there that is what iam talking about..

Comment: @RaymondNijland in most cases it won't even work

Comment: Well user user variable are pretty powerfull if you know you to use them correctly @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @RaymondNijland this works fine: `MSSQL NEWID() -> MySQL UUID() MSSQL CHECKSUM() -> MySQL CRC32()`
The issue now is the `over (partition(` bit

Comment: @user37143 as I already explained, without MySQL 8.0 you *can't* emulate the behaviour. And no, the variable hack can't emulate it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanx, got it. Any ideas as to some work around?

Comment: @user37143 upgrade to MySQL 8.0. Or mention which version you target, in the question itself and the *tags*. You still haven't done that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, sorry, our version is `5.7.23-log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My biggest issue so far has been the RAND((CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) which I
>   do not know how to change to MySQL.

`RAND((CHECKSUM(NEWID())))` should behave identical to [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function in MySQL. So you could simply replace this:

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,16),RAND((CHECKSUM(NEWID())))*(1 - 0.999999999)+0.999999999)
```

With this:

```
CAST(RAND() * (1 - 0.999999999) + 0.999999999 AS DECIMAL(16, 16))
```

- [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e7ad1254e305cabd1062e837b71bbc3)
- [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ca98c9e8719a88554aaa52799415d95)

Comment: Confirm it works, thanx for the help.
Regarding the `over (partition by (` bit, any suggestions? My version is `5.7.23-log`.

Comment: You can use user variables for this (plenty of examples on SO). There should be no problems if you are OK with ordering the results by ID. It is the pivot that you should be worried about.

Comment: @SalmanA how can variables be used for this? The query contains `max(s2.[STEP_NUMBER]) over (partition by s2.[ID]) ` and `min(s2.[EVENT_NUMBER]) over (partition by s2.[ID], s2.[STEP_NUMBER])` - partitioning by *two* fields. And finally, a PIVOT whose equivalent is a `GROUP BY` and FILTER.